NX - run custom generator after generate library
after generating the angular library (nx g @nx/angular:library libs/my-ui-lib) in NX I need to run a custom generator that will generate an additional structure in the library.
It is some way how to run custom generator after angular generator? Is there some "post process action"?
I don't want to create a wrapper generator and call angular generator inside. I would have to have all input parameters in my generator that angular generator needs and it is better to call standard command than some custom.
